# Formatting phone number a certain way

Tags: php

Sorry, I didnt realize I was suppose to say that I have already looked over the other thread dealing with phone numbers. I have tried a few of those and could not get it to work how I needed it. So thats why I decided to ask it myself with the specifics I needed.

I need a function that can format phone number into **(555) 555-5555** format.

Examples of the phone numbers im formatting are:

**5555555555**

**555-555-5555**

Some numbers that are in the array are already in the correct format.

Comment: I have a function that i use that can help you

Comment: @Yeak thanks but I got it working now due to Markus's answer.

Comment: $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
       $length = strlen($phone);
        switch($length) {
            case 7:
                return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2", $phone);
            break;
            case 10:
                return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "($1)$2-$3", $phone);
            break;
            case 11:
                return preg_replace("/([0-9]{1})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1($2)$3-$4", $phone);
            break;
            default:
                return $phone;
            break;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace all non-numeric characters first, and then reformat. Using regular expressions makes this easy.

```
$number = '555-555-5555';
$numberOnly = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
$formattedNumber = preg_replace('/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/', '($1) $2-$3', $numberOnly);

echo $formattedNumber;
```

gives the formatted output:

```
(555) 555-5555
```

Comment: Thanks. Replacing seemed to do the trick. Before I didnt replace and formatted straight away, and while it worked, it ended up with undesired results for some other information in my code, but this seemed to work great.